# What am I missing here? Join Statement/ Group by?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently am new to SQL and I was wondering what the primary difference is between the 2 queries as to why one gives me more records and duplicates and as to why the other gives me the correct output that I am looking for.

Currently this is the desired output I want with this query.

```
    SELECT
          a.EMPLOYEE, 
          m.FIRST_NAME, 
          m.LAST_NAME, 
          m.PROCESS_LEVEL as PL_1

    FROM 
          dbo.vw_PAEMPPOS a 
                           join dbo.COMPLETE_EMPLOYEE_MASTER m on m.EMPLOYEE = a.EMPLOYEE 
                           join dbo.HR_EMPUSERFIELDS s on s.EMPLOYEE = m.EMPLOYEE 

    WHERE END_DATE = '2099-12-31 00:00:00.000' and 
          EMP_STATUS NOT IN ('1A', 'RT', 'SZ', 'T1', 'XD', 'XV', 'ZZ') 

    GROUP BY 
          a.EMPLOYEE, 
          m.LAST_NAME, 
          m.FIRST_NAME, 
          m.PROCESS_LEVEL
```

I then add another another process level to my select and group by and I get more records then before? What am I missing here?

```
      SELECT 
              a.EMPLOYEE, 
              m.FIRST_NAME, 
              m.LAST_NAME, 
              m.PROCESS_LEVEL as PL_1,
              a.PROCESS_LEVEL

      FROM
              dbo.vw_PAEMPPOS a 
                               join dbo.COMPLETE_EMPLOYEE_MASTER m on m.EMPLOYEE = a.EMPLOYEE 
                               join dbo.HR_EMPUSERFIELDS s on s.EMPLOYEE = m.EMPLOYEE 

      WHERE END_DATE = '2099-12-31 00:00:00.000' and 
            EMP_STATUS NOT IN ('1A', 'RT', 'SZ', 'T1', 'XD', 'XV', 'ZZ') 

    GROUP BY 
            a.EMPLOYEE, 
            m.LAST_NAME, 
            m.FIRST_NAME, 
            m.PROCESS_LEVEL, 
            a.PROCESS_LEVEL
```

Comment: You changed the group-by criteria and therefore you won't get the same number of records back. It will be grouped more granularly than the first query in cases where `m.PROCESS_LEVEL` is different than `a.PROCESS_LEVEL`

Comment: You do realize that your use of group by without any aggregate is logically the same as using "DISTINCT". And that implies your top query returns multiple rows for each set of your grouping columns. That, in turn, implies that there is a logic flaw in the query.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question will depend on vw_PAEMPPOS. You may have more than one record per employee in that view. To check, you can run the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM vw_PAEMPPOS
WHERE Employee IN (
  SELECT Employee
  FROM vw_PAEMPPOS
  GROUP BY Employee
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```